# Using a Counter Loop for Environment Variable

Tags: shell-script, variable

I'm trying to write a code that moves files to a .junk directory using the built-in environment variables.  My goal is that all a user would have to do is type sh junk filename1 filename2 filename3... and the script would use $1, $2, $3... to move the files.  Unfortunately I can't quite get the counter loop to work correctly.

```
#!/bin/s

if [ $# = 0 ]
then echo "Usage: junk -l | -p | { filename }*"

elif [ $1 = "-l" ] && [ $HOME/.junk ]
     then ls $HOME/.junk

elif [ $1 = "-p" ] && [ $HOME/.junk ]
     then rm -r $HOME/.junk

elif [ $1 = "$@" ] && [ $HOME/.junk ]
     then echo $#

i=1
s="$"

while [ $i -le $# ]
do
 echo $s$i
 mv $s$i .junk/$i
 i=$(($i+1))
done

fi
```

Comment: What are "built-in environment variables"? Which shell are you using `/bin/s`?

Comment: That is terrible code. `$1` should always be quoted: `"$1"`. What is `[ $HOME/.junk ]` supposed to be/do? And `[ $1 = "$@" ]`? Why does `while [ $i -le $# ]` start with `i=1` instead of `i=0`? What is supposed to happen with a single file argument? `mv $s$i` is probably supposed to be an (unquotes, of course) indirection which would have to be done with `eval` or (better) `"${!i}"`... The counter loop really is the least of your problems.

Comment: Why are you using a loop in the first place? All you really need is `mv "$@" .junk`. Could you explain what your script is doing and why you want the loop?

Comment: @terdon there is one barely possible chance that `mv "$@" ./junk` will present argument list size problems, but that would take a *lot* of junk.

Comment: @mikeserv It is likely that calling the script would be a problem too in that case.

Comment: Correct: `if [ $# = 0 ]` into `if [ $# -eq 0 ]`,...

Answer (score 1):

Some immediate problems:

1. Use `getopts` for argument processing or have a reason why not.
2. If the script is given more than 1 argument, the `"$@"` in the third `elif` will blow it up.
3. Use a `for f in "$@"` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Why?

1. What happens if you type `sh junk --help` ... or some more interesting `mv` option?
2. QED
3. Simpler => Better

Comment: `for f in "$@" ; do` is hardly simpler than `for f ; do` which is the same thing when you're iterating on positionals. Also `while` and `until` allow conditionals - as many as you can put in a compound command list, thought I don't think our asker is making good use of it. One I always use for positionals is `while ${1+:} false ; do` which is pretty simple. It also gives me the freedom of skipping iterations with `shift` as needed.

Comment: @mikeserv Good comment, but it would be a better answer. Just add one sentence at the top pointing out that attempting to treat positional parameters like an array is the wrong idea. It might actually be useful to some other bash beginner and I'll upvote it past my grumpy answer.

Comment: Positional parameters *are* an array. The shell positional `$@`array is the only fully portable shell array there is. And with its special `IFS` handling its really the only one you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

junkdir="$HOME/.junk"
do_list=false
do_purge=false

while getopts 'lp' opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        l) do_list=true  ;;
        p) do_purge=true ;;
        *)
            printf 'Usage: %s [-l|-p] [ name ... ]\n' "$0" >&2
            exit 1
    esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

if [ ! -d "$junkdir" ] && ! "$do_purge"; then
    printf '%s: Missing junk directory "%s"\n' "$0" "$junkdir" >&2
    printf '%s: Re-run with -p to create it\n' "$0" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if "$do_list"; then
    printf 'Current junk in "%s":\n' "$junkdir"
    ls -l "$junkdir"
fi

if "$do_purge"; then
    printf 'Emptying junk directory "%s"\n' "$junkdir"
    rm -rf "$junkdir"
    mkdir "$junkdir"
fi

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    exit
fi

echo 'Junking the following things:'
printf '%s\n' "$@"

mv "$@" "$junkdir"
```

This script implements what it is you're trying to do.  It uses `getopts` to parse the command line flags `-l` and/or `-p`.

I'm setting `do_list` and `do_purge` in the while loop that parses the command line option because I want to control the order in which the `ls` and the `rm` takes place further down.  If a user uses `-lp` or `-pl` I want them to see the contents of the junk directory *before* it is removed.

Removing the junk directory with `-p` also recreates it. I do this with `rm -rf` followed by `mkdir` for simplicity.

After the command line parsing loop, I adjust the positional parameters so that they only contain non-option arguments (names of files and/or directories).

If there are no positional arguments (`$#` is zero), I don't try to run `mv` to move files to the junk directory.